# Django ModelForm doesnt show up

Tags: python, html, django

I made a website before and ModelForm works so ı copy and paste on my current website and it doesnt work, doesnt show up, everything seems right to me .

This is my model,

```
from django.db import models
class AppModel(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Name')
email = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='E-mail')
subject = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Subject')
message = models.TextField(verbose_name='Message')
```

This is my form,

```
from django import forms
from App.models import AppModel

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = AppModel
    fields = '__all__'
```

This is my view,

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import UserForm
def SupportForm(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    context = dict(
    form = form
    )
if form.is_valid():
    
    newForm = form.save()
    return redirect('support')
return render(request,'support.html',context)
```

And This is my html,

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block container %}
{% load static %}

<div class="container" style="height: 100vh;  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
<div>
<h2>Communicate</h2>
<hr>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'support' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->

<button type = "submit" value = "Submit" class = "btn btn-warning">Ekle</button>

</form>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does it show anything else apart from the form?

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem not sure but I think We must create form and its html in the same app